# jQTouch Back Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtouch

I'm using jQTouch to build a UITableView-like interface. However, I'm trying to insert a button with by creating an `<li>` node with `class="back"` but all I get is a stylized, left-facing button that is in the toolbar area (that I've disabled.)

Does anyone know how to get an `<li>` element with `class="back"` without it being stylized as described above?

Comment: the simplest solution, of course, is to rename the class to '.bkg'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by just calling an `onclicked="jQT.goBack();"` for my `<li>` element.

Answer (score 3):

Just noticed in rev 161 of JQtouch that the css class "goback" handles this — does the same as "back" except doesn't apply the built-in styling.

Comment: This works. Make sure to not use camel casing "goBack". The framework will not recognize. Use "goback".

Answer (score 0):

```
class="back" // defined in theme.css
```

is defined as part of jQTouch styling and it has a specific meaning. By using it in to list item you are inheriting those class values.

What DDaviesBrackett is suggesting is that you use a different name for you class

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem where back wasn't working correctly in a similar scenario, this was my fix:

```
var back = function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();
  jQT.goBack();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.back').click(back);
});
```

// comment to allow an edit